# java classes integration with birt

Tags: java, birt

I want to write java classes in BIRT. Let me know the process where do I write my java programs in BIRT.

Comment: [You might want to read this.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your java class in you java package.And there is a data source option in birt call script data using that you can access you java class and get the data to report.
this will be helpful for you!!

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseBIRT/article.html#data_dataset